# multimensional arrays in C++

Tags: java, c++, multidimensional-array

I want to create a function which takes many multidimensional arrays as a parameter and returns another multidimensional array.

For example matrix multiplication, there is 2 arrays Matrix1[n][m] and Matrix2[m][k] and my function have to return Result[n][k].

In java;

```
/**
 * @param m1 Matrix 1
 * @param m2 Matrix 2
 * @return Matrix1*Matrix2
 */
public static long[][] matrixMult(long[][] m1, long[][] m2){
    long[][] mult = new long[m1.length][m2[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < m1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2[0].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m1[0].length; k++) {
                mult[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return mult;
}
```

it's just an example code.

I want to do same thing with C++;

```
int main()
{
    int m1, m2, n1, n2;
    scanf("%d %d", &m1, &m2);
    int matrix1[m1][m2];
    // Take array values
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    int matrix2[n1][n2];
    // Take array values again
    if(m2 == n1){
        // I need to multiply those arrays Matrix1 and Matrix2 and assign the product as a array to Result[][]
        // int result[][] = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to describe problem which is stopping you from finishing your code. Stack Overflow is place where we help solving problems, not free-code-rewriting-service.

Comment: `int matrix1[m1][m2];` is not standard C++ (it is a VLA extension). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Pshemo Problem is when i tried to define an array i got errors -possibly because of syntax- and i don't get it why. Errors have no sense, int** and int[][] are diffrent, convert errors, sizetype errors, i got so many error. That's why i can't explain actual error, because i dont know what's wrong. I don't want to use vector, i need to use arrays. Searched everywhere something like this but i can't find it. And it's why i'm here.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample you could use.

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_t;

matrix_t Mul(const matrix_t& a, const matrix_t& b)
{
    matrix_t mult(a.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) 
    {
        mult[i].reserve(b[0].size()); //avoid push backs while calculating your result
        std::fill(mult[i].begin(), mult[i].end(), 0); // make sure the array is initialized to the desired value

        for (int j = 0; j < b[0].size(); ++j) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < a[0].size(); ++k) 
            {
                mult[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return mult;
}
```

You could also use [OpenCv](http://opencv.org/) which provide many functions to apply operations on matrices.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble of `mult[i].reserve(b[0].size());` and create the result vector like this: `matrix_t mult(a.size(), std::vector<int>(b[0].size()));`